# Catalyst Couldn't load helper "Catalyst::Helper::View::TT"

Tags: perl, catalyst

I follow the book "The Definitive Guide to Catalyst". Now when I run the command "script/lolcatalyst_lite_create.pl view Web TT", I get as follows

> exists "/home/hengaini/LolCatalyst-Lite/script/../lib/LolCatalyst/Lite/View"
>   exists "/home/hengaini/LolCatalyst-Lite/script/../t"
>   Couldn't load helper "Catalyst::Helper::View::TT", "Can't locate Catalyst/Helper/View/TT.pm >in @INC (@INC contains: /home/hengaini/LolCatalyst-Lite/script/../lib /etc/perl /usr/local /lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at (eval 338) line 2.

question:
1.Is Catalyst still popular? Every web framework says good;
2.How to solve above problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

1 - Yes, at least with me :-)

Catalyst is well maintianed. There is no new Perl framework aimed at replacing Catalyst.

2 - Install the missing module:

```
sudo cpan Catalyst::Helper::View::TT
```

Make sure everything is installed

```
sudo cpan Catalyst::Runtime
sudo cpan Catalyst::Devel
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. It was just 'obvious' to me that that module wouldve been installed when I installed the Runtime and Devel! ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Catalyst is quite popular, and has a very active community behind it.

But the issue you've run into there isn't Catalyst specific. It looks like `Catalyst::Helper::View::TT` isn't installed on your server.

Try installing it from CPAN and see how you go. You'll also need to `install Template` ([Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/)) if you haven't already.

*(If you've gotten as far as you have, I guess you know how to install from CPAN!)*